# Pointers on using WCF service to manage local and cloud database

Tags: wcf, cloud

I'm looking for the best way to have a service that will pull data from a local database and pass it to a sql azure database and vise-versa.

example:

Local Database.
Service will pull data with a status of say 'Ready' and pass this data to a method(created from service reference to service hosted in azure) that will handle adding this data to sql azure database, i'll then need change the status of these records in the local database to say 'Sent'.

Then

SQL Azure Database.
Call method in service hosted in azure to send me the data that has a status of 'Completed'.  Use this data to then update the local database records as completed.

Can this be done by a WCF service sitting in the middle?
Do i use a timer to call the methods to push/pull the data as stated above?
When i send data to the SQL azure database if i don't receive an error do i asume that the data has been received at the other end thus allowing me to set tne status in the local database?

Hope nobody fell asleep while reading this :)

Any pointer to tutorial/examples would also help alot.
Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a normal application (possibly a Windows Service) to stand in the middle. There's no reason for it to be a WCF service.

Comment: Hi John is it best practice to use a timer to query/update the database?

Comment: @paul: it is a best practice if you need to do it! If you can use something like the Notification feature of SQL Server to trigger the  update, then do that. Otherwise, I see nothing wrong with polling using a query that simply determines whether anything has changed. When you find that something has changed, then issue the full query that returns all the changed data.